# What was it that Rido did to the Night Class?

Tags: vampire-knight

In the Vampire Knight anime, when the Night Class is getting ready to attack him, Rido holds up one of his hands, from which black shadows shoot out and wrap around the Night Class.

I am wondering, is this a representation of Rido's power as a Pure Blood to force other vampires to obey? Or is it a unique ability he possesses, like the case with other vampires (Aido can freeze stuff, Ruka has hypnosis)?

Answer (score 2):

It's been a long time since I've seen the anime but I vaguely remember Rido's unique power having something to do with some kind of poison effect. Its not literally poison, but a slow, painful draw on one's life-force. If I'm right, then that's definitely not what happened in the scene with the night class. I think it's related to Rido being a pure-blooded vampire, but a little more in depth to his specific family line. This is what really makes him a unique character. Surely if these questions are ever firmly answered, it will only be with further questions.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I'll try to improve my grammar. I've been getting a lot of edits for capitAls.